# Rotating marker in Google Maps Javascript API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I don't do a lot of coding but I have tried to write what I thought would be a simple bit of code that will be ran through phonegap/cordova. Right now all I want it to do is locate me, keep the marker on my location as I move/walk/drive and rotate in the direction I'm traveling with a standard triangle SVG Google marker.

I'm really having a tough time figuring out the rotating/bearing/heading since I don't have an end destination or poly lines to follow. Right now I have it locate fine, put the marker on the map, updates fine and keeps the marker in the center. Of course I'll add a lot more to this but this is the portion I'm having trouble with. I put a ***// in the code of the rotation part I'm trying to fix with the code I thought might work. I'll probably turn it into a variable called heading but it shows the concept.

My problem is I don't know how to get the to and from latlng. I'm using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition to follow the location change so I don't know how to get the previous latlng. Also, if there's an easier way to do what I'm trying to do in general I'm all ears. I feel like I've over thought this but maybe it does take all this.

I removed my api code but other than that this all works as is.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GEOCODING TEST</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        html,
        body {
            height: 100% ;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
            overflow: hidden ;
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ;
            width: 100% ;
            }

        #mapContainer {
            height: 100% ;
            width: 100% ;
            }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MYAPIKEY}" type=
    "text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src=
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapContainer">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mapContainer = $( "#mapContainer" );    
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            mapContainer[ 0 ],
            {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    40.700683,
                    -73.925972
                ),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }
        );

        function addMarker (latitude, longitude){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                ),
                flat: true,
                icon: {
                   path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                   strokeColor : 'red',
                   strokeWeight : 3,
                   scale: 6,
                   ***//rotation: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(from:LatLng, to:LatLng)
                 },
        });

        return( marker );


        }
        function updateMarker( marker, latitude, longitude, label ){

            marker.setPosition(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                )

            );

            if (label){

                marker.setTitle( label );

            }
        }

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            var locationMarker = null;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function( position ){
                    if (locationMarker){
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log( "Initial Position Found" );

                    locationMarker = addMarker(
                        position.coords.latitude,
                        position.coords.longitude,
                        "Initial Position"
                    );

                },
                function( error ){
                    console.log( "Something went wrong: ", error );
                },
                {
                    timeout: (5 * 1000),
                    maximumAge: (1000 * 60 * 15),
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            );

            var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function( position ){

                    console.log( "Newer Position Found" );
                    console.log (position);

                    updateMarker(
                        locationMarker,
                        position.coords.latitude,
                        position.coords.longitude,
                        "Updated / Accurate Position"
                    );
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(
                 position.coords.latitude, 
                 position.coords.longitude);   

      map.setCenter(pos);


                }
            );

            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    // Clear the position watcher.
                    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( positionTimer );
                },
                (1000 * 60 * 5)
            );

        }

    </script>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it is really hard to predict the future, if you don't have a real time heading from the GPS device, use the previous point and the updated point.  That won't be particularly accurate if it isn't moving (or isn't moving fast enough).

```
function updateMarker(marker, latitude, longitude, label) {
  var prevPosn = marker.getPosition();
  marker.setPosition(
    new google.maps.LatLng(
      latitude,
      longitude
    )
  );
  marker.setIcon({
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    scale: 6,
    rotation: google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(prevPosn, marker.getPosition())
  })
  if (label) {
    marker.setTitle(label);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a google library created for this purpose, and it is called **[Geometry Libray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry)**.

A set of Navigation functions is included in this library and will help you very much with calculating distances, heading..etc.

You can find a clear example **[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings)**:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 34, lng: -40.605}
        });

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(
            document.getElementById('info'));

        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          position: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.006}
        });

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          draggable: true,
          position: {lat: 48.857, lng: 2.352}
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'position_changed', update);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'position_changed', update);

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          map: map,
        });

        geodesicPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#CC0099',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          geodesic: true,
          map: map
        });

        update();
      }
```

That polyline is a virtual line that connects the departure, and destination points.